# Is a Primary Key useful in a live data scenario?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm on Postgres 9.5. and using a bigSerial as primary key.

Now I have a table that contains live data. It will be refreshed every minute, meaning the whole data will be **replaced** by a processing job.

Therefore the serial is growing rapidly. (Amount of data that will be replaced is between 5000 and 10000 records)

I'm worrying, that I'll hit the max of bigSerial after letting this run for a year or so. So I thought about getting rid of this id as I don't need a reference to these data. (I'lll always do something like `Select * from live_data (and delete afterwards)`

Is there any reason why I should keep the serial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the max value of bigSerial is `9223372036854775807` lets take that you will recreate about 10000 rows per minute so it takes

(9223372036854775807/10000) / 525600 = **1754827245.05** years to waste all bigSerial.

So i think it's quite safe to use it in your task. But you could consider whether it is possible to use natural primary key or just 1..N rownumber as primary key. It depends on your task.

Comment: yeah, I thought about using a pk containing 2 columns that will be unique together

Comment: The natural key is good thing in most of cases. So if it is exists just use it.

Comment: @Christian If you really replace the **complete** data in the table, you could also restart the sequence: `truncate table foobar restart identity`